# Unable to understand result of this c program

Tags: c, binary

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
  int i;
  i = 011;
  printf("%d",i);
}
```

This program gives output as 9. I don't know the reason for that. Please help me to figure out why this program is giving this output.

Comment: Do you know how to represent octal number in `C` ?

Comment: Octal constant literal `011`

Comment: `0b011` can use by GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

011 is octal number due to 0 preceding it

```
011 = 1*(8^1) + 1*(8^0)
    = 1*8 + 1*1
    = 8 +1
    = 9 in decimal(%d)
```

0x for hex and only digits(i.e 9) for decimal

Answer (score 7):

In C, you can represent the value 9 by:

- Hexadecimal (Base 16): **0x9**
- Decimal (Base 10): **9**
- Octal (Base 8): **011**

Comment: we can also use capital `X` for hex e.g. `0XFF`

Answer (score 5):

In C/C++/Java, hex numbers begin with `0x`. Octal numbers begin with `0`.

`011` is octal of `9`

Comment: And before you ask why, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1835465/1870232)