# ASCII character 14 (and others) when assigned in string in C

Tags: c, char, gdb, non-ascii-characters

Debugging the following code in GDB:

```
char* input = malloc(2);
input[0] = 14;
input[1] = 0;
```

The value of the string in memory according to GDB is:

```
input = "\016"
```

Likewise,

```
char* input = malloc(2);
input[0] = 16;
input[1] = 0;
```

input in memory is `"\020"`.

Why is this the case? Why doesn't ASCII value 14 map to char `\016`? Then, why does ASCII value 16 map to `\020` in memory?

EDIT: To add further confusion, using the following code:

```
char* input = malloc(2);
input[0] = 20;
input[1] = 0;
```

By running the above code segment in gdb and using the following command:

```
p input
```

the resulting value that is printed is:

```
$1 = 0x604010 "\020"
```

This leads me to believe that value of string input is "\020".

Two ASCII numbers map to the same contents `"\020"` (namely 16 and 20).

Comment: confusingly, "\020" is used twice. One to represent 16 in octal (as you said) but also it seems that ASCII value 20 is also represented as "\020".

Comment: @Peabrain `input is the string "\020"` That's not the same as `input[0] = 20;` which  you wrote next. `it seems that ASCII value 20 is also represented as "\020"` No, it's not. Not sure what makes you think so, since you posted no real code, and no step-by-step of what you are actually doing.

Comment: just copy and paste the last code segment then debug it in GDB. I am getting the value "\020" when you use the command "p input". I add that it in for further clarification.

Comment: @Peabrain ["\020" = { 16, 0 }](https://onlinegdb.com/ryYjKJ0xu).

Comment: @Peabrain: do you paste C code into GDB? or did you change the source code and run GDB again on the executable **without** recompiling it? This would explain the surprising behavior reported...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`14` is written `016` in octal (base eight). The syntax `'\016'` uses octal for historical reasons, namely antique computers from the 60s that had 6-bit chars crammed in 12-bit, 18-bit or even 36-bit words for which octal digits seemed a perfect representation for groups of 3 bits.

Traces of this can be found in the C syntax for character and string constants (borrowed from C by many languages) and the permission flags in Unix file systems (eg: `chmod` and `umask` arguments).

`16` is `'\020'`, `20` is `'\024'` and `32` (ASCII space) is `'\040'` or `'\x20'`.

Comment: The C literal string octal sequence dates from 1972 on PDP-11 computers which used 8 bit characters.  Earlier in DEC's history, there were other rather strange word sizes, but few of them had much effect on later designs.

Comment: @wallyk: the PDP-11 was **the** modern machine of its time, but the Unix team at Bell Labs used PDP-8 machines before that, with a 12-bit address space. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13960625/4593267).

Answer (score 1):

This record `\016` represents an octal escape sequence. Its value in the decimal notation is equal to `14`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

```
octal-escape-sequence:
    \ octal-digit
    \ octal-digit octal-digit
    \ octal-digit octal-digit octal-digit
```

The compiler could represent the value also as a hexadecimal escape sequence like `\xE`.

This octal escape sequence `\020` represents the decimal number `16`. The number `20` written as an octal escape sequence will look like `\024`.