# Why does 01232 == 666?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if I could quickly remove the 0 from 01232 by dividing it by 1 in my browsers console but all of a sudden it gives me 666.

[image: Opera GX Browser Console]

So I was curious and tried this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the leading zero makes the whole number be treated as octal

And 2 + 3x8 + 2x8^2 + 1x8^3 = 666

Answer (score 0):

The leading `0` in `01232` means that the rest of the number is interpreted as octal, representing

```
1 x 8^3   +   2 x 8^2   +   3 x 8^1   +   2 x 8^0

=

512 + 128 + 24 + 2

=

666
```

This prefix (analogous to `0x` for hexadecimal) dates back to the early days of Unix; [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1835465/1090302).

Comment: You mean analogous to the modern [`0o`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal#valid_octal_numbers)?